# Changing size of the dots in a balloon plot and keeping zero values

Tags: r, ggplot2

With these data

```
Data <- structure(list(ObsVal = c(22L, 50L, 8L, 15L, 54L, 30L, 11L, 90L, 
6L, 53L, 9L, 42L, 72L, 40L, 60L, 58L, 1L, 20L, 37L, 2L, 50L, 
68L, 20L, 19L, 58L, 5L), Porp = c(0.0909090909090909, 0.02, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.272727272727273, 0.455555555555556, 0, 0.452830188679245, 
0.111111111111111, 0.404761904761905, 0, 0.025, 0.0166666666666667, 
0.120689655172414, 0, 0.1, 0.108108108108108, 0, 0, 0.0294117647058824, 
0, 0, 0.310344827586207, 0), Pred = c(26, 52, 6, 15, 39, 30, 
13, 85, 8, 62, 5, 48, 92, 52, 71, 68, 1, 28, 47, 1, 41, 106, 
29, 19, 39, 7)), .Names = c("ObsVal", "Porp", "Pred"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

and this code

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x=ObsVal, y=Pred, size=Porp))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method=lm, color="red")+
    theme_bw()+
    guides(size=FALSE)
p
```

I can make this plot[image]

but the dots are too small.  When I increase the size with the code

```
p+scale_size_area(max_size=10)
```

The dots get larger, but I loose the values where Porp is zero.  [image]

I tried to add 1 to all Porp values, but then the sizes were all the same.

It is possible to increase the size of the dots as in the 2nd fig, but also include points were Porp is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use `scale_size_continuous` and its `range` argument. E.g. something like this:

```
p + scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 10))
```